# MongoDB Authentication Not Working Despite Configuring It

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB 5.0.6 installed and despite adding an admin user and database user via mongosh, as well as editing the /etc/mongod.conf to include authorization: "enabled", it still allows for anonymous users to connect without credentials. How can I force a login for any connection? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you restart the MongoDB?

Yes, you can always connect to a MongoDB even without credentials. However, apart from harmless commands like `help` or `getMongo()` you cannot execute anything.

Comment: Thanks, restarting worked and now that I know you can connect without credentials, that has cleared up any remaining confusion.